# How do I save my inputted text inside a state using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I want to input a some text string, something like `here's some random text` in the text box.  I want that `here's some random text` to be displayed via `alert()` inside `handleSubmit()` function.

As of now, `random 123`, which's inside `StoryTextReducer` does indeed display via `alert()` inside `handleSubmit()` function because it's hard coded.

But I want to manually enter some text in `<textarea>`, save that text inside `storyTextValue` (inside `StoryTextReducer`) state followed by displaying it via `alert()` inside `handleSubmit()` function.

What am I doing wrong and how would I achieve this?

Here's `StoryTextReducer`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
        alert("Article saved" + '\n' + this.props.storyTextValue);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea rows="2" cols="25" ></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE})

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Here's `StoryTextReducer`:

```
import * as actionType from '../store/actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    storyTextValue: 'random 123'
};

const StoryTextReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                storyTextValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default StoryTextReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine ..try adding state to top of the component.

```
state = { 
 value:null
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the state value since its already updated. And i believe setting state again inside submit is not required.

You can pass `this.state.value` instead of `event.target.value` to make `API` call.

```
handleSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.storyTextValueRedux(this.state.value);
    alert("Article saved" + '\n' + this.state.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you might have missed:

1) You are not passing the value in storyTextValueRedux in the mapDispatchToProps. Your code should look like this

```
storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})
```

2) You are listening for the wrong actionType in your reducer. I'm guessing what you want to be listening to is

```
case actionType.STORY_VALUE:
```

3) Instead of updating the value on form submit you should attach to the textarea directly similar to the input field. (Might want to change the method name to something else)

```
<textarea value={this.props.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleSubmit} rows="2" cols="25" />
```

All in all updating individual field values in the store is doable but it might be better to take a look at how other people handle this such as [Redux-Forms](https://redux-form.com/) or a generalized wrapper component (e.g. [Mark Erikson's blog series](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/))